# asp.net mvc load related data from multiple contexts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have a MVC .Net Core 3.1 project with 2 contexts. One is the standard Identity context and the other is the application context.
These are stored as 2 separate databases on the server.

In my application I have an entity 'Project' and it has a field 'ProjectLeadUserId' in which I store the ID of that user from AspNetUsers.

When I list all of the open projects I would like to show the 'UserName' from AspNetUsers, rather than the GUID related to each of the projects.

Normally I would have a foreign key between the two so that in my view I could do something like:

```
project.ProjectLead.UserName
```

But I cant workout how to set that up in my entity as the FK would be in a different context.

Is this possible, or have I caused myself an issue by separating the Identity and application contexts?

**Edit:**
Ignoring the foreign key issue as I can deal with that in the application logic. Is there a way to load the related data when multiple contexts are involved.
e.g. When I get a list of projects, can I load the related AspNetUsers data, using the AspNetUsers.Id and Project.ProjectLeadUserId?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from SQL Server [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15#BeforeYouBegin):

> FOREIGN KEY constraints can reference only tables within the same database on the same server. Cross-database referential integrity must be implemented through triggers. For more information, see CREATE TRIGGER.

It's not possible for you to have a foreign key across different databases in SQL Server.

If the 2 contexts targeted the same DB, I think what you want would still not be possible.

In my past projects I've usually seen people extending the IdentityDbContext to create their DB context and using only that.